# How do I compare local and remote asset bundle versions without actually downloading the asset bundle?

Tags: unity-game-engine, caching, version, assetbundle

### What I'm trying to do

I'm working on a sort of portal to showcase several of the projects my organization has made in Unity. To keep it flexible and light, I've designed an architecture using asset bundles:

1. When the user downloads the portal, all they download is a bootstrap scene that loads in the main menu scene automatically. This keeps the initial download very light and allows them to get going quicker. Also, having everything else in asset bundles maximizes the amount of 3D content we can update after delivery.
2. When the main menu downloads and loads, the user is presented with a list of projects. Each project is tied to an asset bundle that can be downloaded on-demand. That way, if they are interested in one project and not another, they don't have to waste time and disk space downloading a project they'd never explore.
3. If they haven't already downloaded a specific project's asset bundle, they are prompted by a button to download it. If they have an older version, they are prompted to update it. If all up-to-date, they are prompted to visit it.

---

### The Problem

The problem I'm having is two-fold:

1. I'm unsure what is the best library to use to do what I'm trying to do. Currently, there seem to be two ways of downloading asset bundles WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload and UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle. Not to mention, Unity just teased ResourceManager and addressable assets at Unite 2017 (but that seems far off).
2. No matter which library I use, neither seems to have a built-in way of checking a local or remote asset bundle version without downloading the bundle itself.

---

### What I've done so far

In the meantime, I've used UWR to download the remote bundle manifest and Regexed for the CRC and hash. Now looking at Caching.IsVersionCached to Regex the local version and compare, but that method is obsolete...

Any ideas?

Comment: why not use a version number with each asset bundle and keep track of what you have and what the online asset has (build a supper quick api to get the version numbers) then if the number is the same your good, if the online one is greater than local then you need to update and if there is no local number you obviously haven't downloaded it...

Comment: @user3797758 I have thought about doing that and it is certainly an option. However, incrementing the version numbers would need to be done manually in this case, rather than just using the crc and hash generated by the assetbundle when it is created. No problem for me, but I fear it would be something overlooked by our 3D artists who would be the ones updating the assetbundles.

Comment: Why would it have to be done manually? If you build an internal tool to upload the assets (like an upload thingy on a web page) it can look at the previous number and base the number one on that and do any other upload tasks you need it to do like updating the DB after it is up, add notes to a change log or whatever you need. From the artists point of view they just upload the file and it works.

Comment: Yeah, but see, now we're talking about making an upload tool and a database and an api. All for generating, looking up, and comparing version numbers that are already made and available without all of that. I found that there are undocumented overloads for the IsVersionCached method, so I've been using that and am getting close. I will post the solution if I get there.